# Reading JSON from Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, virtual-machine

I am trying to read JSON data which is stored in VM notes. Below is the command i execute to get the VM notes

```
Get-VM testbox |format-list Notes
```

The output is

```
Notes : {
            "Program":  "AAA",
            "Project":  "BBBB"
        }
```

I want to read the value of Program into a variable. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ConvertFrom-JSON` to parse the JSON-value in your `notes`-property. I'd store the converted notes in a variable just in case you need to access `Project` or another part of the json later. Try:

```
$vm = Get-VM testbox
$notes = $vm.Notes | ConvertFrom-JSON
$mynewvar = $notes.program
```

Comment: How can i get this value for a Virtual machine that is hosted on the machine from where the script is executed.    $vm = Get-VM testbox dosent work from remote machine. I would need to use Invoke-command

Comment: Huh? First you ask how to use it locally (which the code above already does), then you talk about remoting. What do you need? To query a remote server, use `$vm = Get-VM -Name "testbox" -ComputerName "someHyperVServer"`

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid, if it was this would work:

```
 (Get-VM -VMName TestBox).notes | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Valid Json:

```
{
    "Notes":
    {
        "Program":  "AAA",
        "Project":  "BBBB"
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON is valid.. At least `ConvertFrom-Json` is happy. The `Notes:` part is the property name for the PowerShell-object when it's displayed using list-view (like `Format-List`) in the consle. His JSON-notes value starts with the curly-braces

Comment: I see, I seem to have misunderstood that part of his question

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked for me.  $test=(Get-VM -VMName TestBox).notes | ConvertFrom-Json    $test.Program

Answer (score -1):

Totally untested (and can't test right now) but something like:

```
Get-VM testbox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Notes | ConvertFrom-Json
```

[Documentation for `ConvertFrom-Json` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)

Comment: if you pass `Format-List` to `ConvertFrom-Json` it won't work since your are passing a format object rather than a json object

Comment: @Dave that's totally right... I've edited to change it to `Select-Object`... still can't test it, but it should work in theory :-)

Comment: You need to use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Notes` otherwise you are getting an object with a single property named notes rather than the string value of the notes property

Comment: I knew I still had something off :-) , thanks @Dave, fixed